# gcloud GKE restarts pods when adding node pool

Tags: cluster, google-kubernetes-engine

We're using gcloud kubernetes engine for machine learning algorithm development.  We set up a cluster with one pod for code development, then start a temporary node-pool with 256 preemptible minions to test the algorithm on our data set.  A developer ssh'es into the development pod, edits code, then runs a kuberenetes job on the minion pool.

The problem is, when we create the minions node pool, the development pods in the default pool often (not always) get killed and restarted.  Why?  It usually takes about 3-5 minutes for the minion node pool to get started.  It seems like gcloud has to upgrade the default node pool to accommodate the minions node-pool.  Is there a way to preallocate the cluster to avoid the restart, or reduce the startup time for the minions?

Here are the commands I'm using:

1. create the initial cluster:

   ```
   gcloud beta container clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME \
           --machine-type=n1-highmem-4 \
           --min-cpu-platform="Intel Sandy Bridge" \
           --num-nodes=1 \
           --enable-autoscaling \
           --min-nodes=1 \
           --max-nodes=4 \
           --disk-size=50 \
           --node-labels=algoalpha=control \
           --scopes=cloud-platform,cloud-source-repos-ro
   ```

   create cluster script: https://gist.github.com/4590040f27f3cf17562baae5ae245b60
2. create the minions

   ```
   gcloud beta container node-pools create algoalpha-minions \
          --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
          --enable-autoscaling \
          --num-nodes=$NUM_NODES \
          --min-nodes=0 \
          --max-nodes=$((NUM_NODES * 2)) \
          --preemptible \
          --machine-type=n1-highmem-16 \
          --disk-size=20 \
          --min-cpu-platform="Intel Sandy Bridge" \
          --node-labels=algoalpha=minion \
          --node-taints=cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible="true":NoSchedule
   ```

   create minions script: https://gist.github.com/1391658975d3a28444ac823233c334da

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hello @noelbk, I am a little confused, would you clarify if you meant that you SSH to the development node (VM instance) rather than pod, and that the nodes (instances) are being killed in the default node pool? If that’s the case it could be that the autoscaler of the default node pool need to be disabled. Let me know.

Comment: We ssh into the pod itself not the node where the pod is running.  Hmmm... disable the autoscaler you say.  That's a good idea.  I like having the autoscaler on the minions pool.  I'll look for a way to disable the autoscaler on the default pool